# Dataflow-between-ACC-and-Trimble-Connect

Tags: autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud, autodesk-realitycapture

We work within Antea Belgium with ACC and are looking at the possibility of publishing to Trimble Connect. Are there any known flows for this? Or which work around is the most convenient?

Thanks in advance.

The most possible workflow or people who want to improve this together.

Comment: The two possible directions I can think of are: ACC:Connect and Data Exchange Connector.  However, it looks none of them have provided connector for Trimble, though in technical, you could use ACC (APS) API to get files/data and use Trimble API to transfer data to Timble. So it sounds you are asking a handy connector or you are also fine to write code yourself?

Comment: as to the handy connector of Data Exchange , you could raise your voice at roadmap: https://aps.autodesk.com/data-exchange-roadmap

Comment: in addition, are you concerned on files (documents), model data or other ACC data (issue, rfi etc..) ?